# PHP data won't be added to tables

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have this code that will add to the lvl_log table and alter the percentage in the creature table when this page is clicked, and when I click the page, no data is added to the tables.

```
    //Add percentage if it hasn't been clicked yet
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$cq = "SELECT ip FROM lvl_log WHERE ID = '$id' AND IP = '$ip'";
$cresults = mysql_query($cq);

if(mysql_num_rows($cresults) == 0)
{
    if($percent != 100)
    {
        $newpercent = $percent + 5;

                    mysql_query("UPDATE Creatures SET Percent='$newpercent' WHERE id='$id'");
            }

            $sql="INSERT INTO lvl_log (id, ip)
            VALUES('".$id."', '".$ip."')";


            mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }
```

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_query` in new applications, and you **must** be very careful about [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) any and all values used in your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a query, always check the result.

For debugging purposes, you can add a statement to the end of each query to get immediate feedback:

```
mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

This will reveal the exact reason for the failure.

In production code, you should consider logging the error instead of displaying it on-screen. You can do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query( $query );

if ( false === $result ) {
    // Log the output of mysql_error() or send an email to an admin
}
```

Finally, be aware that the `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/migration55.deprecated.php) in current versions of PHP. Consider updating your code to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php).

Comment: +1: Basic rule of thumb. Never **EVER** assume an operation with an external resource (file, remote url, database, etc...) succeeds. Assume failure and code accordingly.

Comment: @Bojangles Regarding your edit: I find that placing the boolean value first helps to avoid assignment-vs-comparison errors. `( false = $result )` will be flagged as an error, while `( $result = false )` will cause a silent logical error.